# 2 Rows With Two Text/Image Combos

Tags: html, css

I need to create two rows with a text box/image on the left and a text box/image on the right.  I have tried this syntax, but this only creates 1 row - how do I create 2 rows?

```html
<div>
  <span style="float: left">
  <font size="30" color="red">Row 1 Left 1</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\1.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
  <span style="float: right">
  <font size="30" color="red">Row 1 Rightl</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\4.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span style="float: left">
  <font size="30" color="red">Row 2 Left</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\2.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
  <span style="float: right">
  <font size="30" color="red">Row 2 Right</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\3.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
This is what I get when I try syntax suggested
[image]

This is what my desired display is
[image]

Comment: Looks like it creates two rows to me...although you should clear the floats and stop using `<font>`  as it's been deprecated and is now obsolute.

Comment: Well, your HTML has two outer containers which could, with the right styling, be considered rows. What is clear is that you're using ancient styling practices. Avoid inline styles as you have curently and use CSS. Moreover, the `<font` tag is almost never used these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `clear:both` in the second row's CSS, after the float values.

Comment: I only had to use clear:both on the 1st <span> in the second row.  Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Use `display:block`; to root div. on child `width:1/2` and `float:left` and `float:right`

```css
.cont{
 display:block;  
}

.cont-left{
  float: left;
  width:50%;
  }


.cont-right{
  float: right;
  width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="cont-left">
   <span>
  <font size="30" color="red">Row1 Left</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\1.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
   <span>
  <font size="30" color="red">Row1 Right</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\4.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-right">
   <span >
  <font size="30" color="red">Row2 Left</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\2.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
  <span >
  <font size="30" color="red">Row2 Right</font><br> 
  <img src="C:\3.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
   </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That is very close.  It does not have the ones I have flagged as right on the right side of the page (starting with the right margin)

Comment: After running this code  I can see that the 2nd two is on the right

Comment: Look at my edit.  While your syntax does create two rows with two columns, column 2 is left centered and I want it right centered in the images displayed in my edit.

Comment: See my edited answer. and inform me is it what you want.